# Include a sidebar on the static front page of twenty thirteen

Tags: sidebar

This is my first child theme (2013) attempt and its going along nicely (with a huge learning curve), but I can't seem to find out how to include a sidebar to my static home page or front page.  I know I could use a post for my home page, but I've have things set up nicely as a static page and feel there must be a simple way to rectify this. I hope...

Comment: Are you using the Twentythirteen Theme? You should be able to add widgets (WP-Admin > Appearance > Widgets) to the sidebar called "Secondary Sidebar" which will appear on posts and pages. Here's a quick video explaining for the Twenty Thirteen theme: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXhvQLhBb-c

Comment: I am using twenty thirteen and in fact made a child theme that I'm working with.  I did add a bunch of pages to the widget page (wpadmin/appearance/widgets) .  This is a "Static" front page and the sidebar works perfectly on every page throughout the site with the exception of its absence on the home page.  It will appear on the home page if I give up the "Static" option and run it as a post page, but I don't really want to go that option unless forced to.

Comment: Double check your settings. I just set up a new install of WordPress and created a TwentyThirteen child theme. I set the "Sample" page as my homepage (Static) and was able to render widgets in the sidebar: https://cl.ly/1s3w2n3h1l34 Here are my settings: https://cl.ly/0O210w0o0W24 and my widget settings: https://cl.ly/2V1d1J1Z3g32 Note that my widgets for the "homepage" are in the Secondary Widget area.

Comment: What I didn't realize was I needed to set

Comment: Sorry, I got a phone call and didn't realize there was a five minute rule on editing!  This is my full reply  :::::::::::::::It is now fixed!  I didn't know I needed to set my "Home Page" Page Temple setting to "default".  This setting was located on Admin/Pages/Home in the lower part after the page content.  This is the link that explained this:  https://www.simplethemes.com/support/viewthread/1712/#5212

Thanks again for your help Tom!

Comment: No problem glad that worked well for you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer from comments in original question:

Double check your settings. I just set up a new install of WordPress and created a TwentyThirteen child theme. I set the "Sample" page as my homepage (Static) and was able to render widgets in the sidebar: cl.ly/1s3w2n3h1l34 Here are my settings: cl.ly/0O210w0o0W24 and my widget settings: cl.ly/2V1d1J1Z3g32 Note that my widgets for the "homepage" are in the Secondary Widget area